# Don't require approval of suggested edits that involve only images

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, images

I have edited a lot of posts on Stack Overflow where all I have needed to do was add in images. The user gives the link to an image, either because he is unaware of the in-question image ability, or he doesn't have enough rep. So I am proposing that if the only edit that is done to a question is adding in those images, we could just let the edit pass through the system without checking it, instead of wasting the edit patrol's time.

Comment: Counter proposal: Focus on doing more substantial edits that just adding an image _that's already there_, at least until you reach 2K rep and your edits don't need to be reviewed anymore. There are tons of posts out there where your time would be much better spent and your edits much more appreciated.

Comment: @Yannis You make a good point, but if the user has a very solid question, but all that is needed is the images, then why not have that option without wasting other's time

Comment: We do have that option, we have an extremely large pool of users with 2K+ rep ;)

Comment: Of the last four suggestions you've made: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1895684), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1967185), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1868355), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1773377), it looks like only one didn't really require any extra work. As an aside, it looks like you're doing a lot of solid editing and (righfully) getting your suggestions regularly approved. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Er, that comment was meant to say "Of the last four suggestions you've made _to inline images_..."

Comment: Given that I've seen anonymous users try to vandalize posts with images of overweight gentlemen and Goatse, and even registered users try to insert spam this way, I think removing oversight would be a terrible idea.

Answer (score 4):

Once a user has enough reputation (2000) it is possible to directly edit a post. At that point that person is considered trusted enough by the community to directly edit posts in a way which adds quality to the content.

Presumably the reason that edits are required to be approved for those under 2000 reputation was from low quality edits. I feel that images are a place where this request could **really** be exploited.

It would be much harder to go around fixing all of the weird NSFW pictures placed in by new users than it would to simply check a linked image and approve the edit which is the status quo. Not to mention much safer for all those users who browse at work.